# Rails atom partial rendering 'content' empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, render, partial, atom-feed

My atom file is outputting a different content bracket locally then it is on heroku

Locally the xml file is outputting

```
<content>  &lt;div class="category-wrap"&gt;
&lt;p class="category"&gt;Whatever:&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;div class="lead"&gt;
    &lt;div class="photo-wrap"&gt;&lt;img src="pn.png"&gt;&lt;/div&gt; 
    &lt;p class="description"&gt;
      &lt;b&gt;&lt;a href="lome.com"&gt;I was all like ye whatveer&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/b&gt; | Name: Robert Hellsing | Email: &lt;a href="MAILTO:budabakasha@gmail.com"&gt;budabakasha@gmail.com&lt;/a&gt; | &lt;a href="ho"&gt;Website&lt;/a&gt;  | &lt;a href="bro"&gt;Twitter&lt;/a&gt;  | &lt;a href="chill"&gt;Linkedin&lt;/a&gt;  | Budget: $50000 
    &lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;
</content>
```

but on heroku it's empty

```
<content></content>
```

Also it's supposed to be rendering a partial in html which it's not doing. "& lt;" instead of brackets

This is my atom.builder file

```
atom_feed do |feed|
  feed.title "Workshop Leads"
  feed.updated @leads.maximum(:updated_at)
   @leads.each do |lead|
    feed.entry lead do |entry|
    entry.title lead.title
    entry.author do |author|
       author.name lead.name
    end
  entry.content render :partial => 'lead_render.atom.erb', :type => 'html'
 end
end
end
```

Here's the partial that it's trying to render

```
<% @leads.today.most_recent.group_by(&:category).each do |category, leads| %>
      <div class="category-wrap">
        <p class="category"><%= category %>:</p>
        <% leads.each do |lead| %>
        <% puts lead.title %>
            <div class="lead">
            <div class="photo-wrap"><img src="<%= lead.photo %>"></div> 
            <p class="description">
              <b><a href="<%= lead.url %>"><%= lead.title %></a></b> | Name: <%= lead.name %> | Email: <a href="MAILTO:<%= lead.email %>"><%= lead.email %></a> <% if lead.website.present? %>| <a href="<%= lead.website %>">Website</a> <% end %> <% if lead.twitter.present? %>| <a href="<%= lead.twitter %>">Twitter</a> <% end %> <% if lead.linkedin.present? %>| <a href="<%= lead.linkedin %>">Linkedin</a> <% end %> <% if lead.budget.present? %>| Budget: $<%= lead.budget %> <% end %>
            </p>
            </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to the atom_feed not having a value.  Have you verified that the atom_feed has a value?

You could just add something to your view like

```
<%= "Atom feed value: #{atom_feed.inspect}" %>
```